# systemverilog: use of unsized & unbased literal in comparison

Tags: system-verilog, literals

I've looked thru the LRM, haven't found a clear answer...  How is the following interpreted:

```
logic [7:0] data;
logic       sig_out;

assign  sig_out = (data == '1);
```

Will it be interpreted as:

```
assign sig_out = (data == 8'hFF);
```

Do sim & synthesis interpret this differently?

thx

PB&J

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but am struggling to see how `sig_out = (data == '1)` could be interpretted any differently to `sig_out = (data == 8'hFF)`. What had you in mind?

Answer (score 3):

5.7.1 Integer literal constants of the 1800-2012 LRM explains that `'1` has the width of the value based on the context where it is used. When using it in a self-determined context, it has a width of 1 bit. Table 11-21 explains that the operands of relational operators in a context sized to the largest operand

So '1 in your context is 8'hff.

Answer (score 0):

**It works as 8'hff.**

Consider the below code, with it's output -

```
module top();
  logic [7:0] data;
  logic       sig_out;

  assign  sig_out = (data == '1);  

  initial
    begin
      data = 'h01;
      #1 $display("sig_out - %0h", sig_out);  
      data = 'h0f;
      #1 $display("sig_out - %0h", sig_out);  
      data = 'hff;
      #1 $display("sig_out - %0h", sig_out);  
    end
endmodule
```

Output -

```
sig_out - 0
sig_out - 0
sig_out - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

'1 means all ones, so if data is 8 bit wide then data = 8'hff.
If you meant to write the value 8'h01 in a context determined length way, use 'b1 which will be interpreted in this case as 8'h01.